# how to connect blockchain node over cloud?

Tags: cloud, blockchain, smartcontracts, go-ethereum

I am creating a one private blockchain network over cloud with the help of 2 ubuntu instances. But I am unable to connect 2 nodes. Even I have checked it with ping with its internal Ips and both are working perfectly.

I have follow below command to do that,

sudo geth --datadir="ethdata" --verbosity 10 --ipcdisable --port 30303 --networkid 15 --nodiscover console --allow-insecure-unlock  --unlock "public address"  --password password --http --http.port "8000" --http.addr "0.0.0.0" –http.corsdomain "*" --http.api "eth,net,web3,miner,debug,personal,rpc"

admin.addPeer("enode://7ac1...2337f8@xxx:xxx:xx:xxx:30303?discport=0")

Same Setup I have tried it over 2 different local system where I am able to connect it successfully.

Do anyone know about this ? is there any problem with ports over cloud or something else ? I have also tried it with different ports and network ids but could not able to connect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve this issue by adding ports into my security group over cloud. Before, I had added only one port 8000 into the security group, but face the same problem. After that I have added all the mentioned ports that I have used (8000 and 30303) for both nodes. As a result I am able to connect it blockchain node. Also tested with mining where blocks are synchronizing.